# Android application data implementation / passing data between activities

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I have looked, but can't find a question here or anywhere that is quite the same as mine. I'm also new to android development, so I'm trying to find out the best way to solve this programming problem.

I will give an example of what I am trying to do.
I define a container object that contains some sort of data structure (say an arrayList) of objects of a different class. The main activity displays a listView of all the objects in the arrayList. When the user picks an item from the list, I need to open a new activity that displays the fields for that object, which the user can edit. The user changes the fields, presses save, and is redirected to the first activity.

In order for this to work, I would need to pass the second activity the object. I understand that I can use Serializable or Parcelable to pass the object, but I need to be able to edit the object and send it back. My C++ brain says to just use pass-by-reference, but my understanding is that that is not available in Java.

I took a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3 , but I don't think any of the solutions offered here solve my problem.

I am sorry I am new to Android and Java; most of my experience is in C++. Am I just thinking about the problem wrong?

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: have a closer look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You intuition is right. The correct way to do what you are describing is (1) implement the `Parcelable` interface in the objects that you want to pass between activities; (2) pass the clicked on object via an `Intent` to the next `Activity` or `Fragment`; (3) reload/refresh the list.

First step is implementing `Parcelable`. The [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) are pretty straight forward and if you look around there are a lot of examples on how to get this done.

You will most likely be displaying your `ArrayList` of objects in a `ListView`. You can do this as a standalone view, by adding a `ListView` to the layout of an `Activity` or by using a `ListFragment` which extends `Fragment`. In both cases there are methods that can tell you which item in the list is clicked. For the `ListView` you can implement an `onItemClick` listener which will give you the position in your list that was clicked on. In the `ListFragment` there is an `onListItemClicked` method that will do roughly the same thing. You should check out the documentation for these classes.

Once you know the position that is clicked on you can get the object that was click and pass it via `Intent` to the next `Activity` (or send it via an argument in a `Bundle` if you are starting a new fragment).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityYouWantToStart.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", object);
startActivity(intent)
```

This will send the object to the next activity (ActivityYouWantToStart). To retrieve it, you can implement the following in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` method

```
Bundle stuffYouSent = getIntent().getExtras();
if(stuffYouSent != null){
     Object o = stuffYouSent.getParcelable("KEY");
     //do something
}
```

Naturally you can change the class from object to whatever you sent just cast your result accordingly.

To get the object back to the original activity you essentially repeat this process in reverse. Make your edits and when you're done pass by intent back. When the object is received you can re-add it to the list or reload the entire list depending on how the list view was implemented.

**Edit - startActivityForResult**

Instead of simply starting the next activity you can use `startActivityForResult` when you know you will be returning back to the first activity. You can see [one example here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) but in your context:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityYouWantToStart.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", object);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Here you are still passing the object to the next activity but specifying a "REQUEST_CODE" that indicates the action to perform when the intent is received. When the intent starts the second activity you handle the intent as you normally would. When you're finished you pass the data back to the first activity as follows

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Here the RESULT_OK indicates that the action is completed. This time, instead of starting the activity like you did before, a special method will be called:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //do something
}
```

Be sure to override this method in your first activity and handle the result. It will return the the extra to your first activity where you can then update the list. The result code and request code can be used to switch functions if multiple activities are returning data.

Comment: tell him how to startActivityForResult... that would react on return from previous activity and getting that resouce bundle

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer! I guess, though, my question is sort of: is it bad for performance to pass in the object, edit it, pass it back, then copy the edited one on top of the original one selected?

Comment: Depends on the object - I would not pass large image files via intent but if you're using classes with a few primatives it should not be a problem.